# phpmyadmin Wordpress MetaKeys

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have an error on my wordpress site which I found the cause being a capital in the user meta keys. IE "City" and "Country" as opposed to "city" and "country"

I'm trying to figure out a way to change thousands of user meta keys with capitals to lowercase equivalents. Any suggestions as to how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to lowercase with the [LOWER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function. The query below will convert all meta keys to lowercase.

```
UPDATE usermeta SET meta_key = LOWER(meta_key)
```